# how can i insert CALLBACK code in my code

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, callback, firebase-authentication

When I created JOIN Action and LOGIN Action on Android app,
Aa problem has occurred.
Working with MVP pattern in LOGIN Action.
But the results on the logins aren't exactly what I want.
I'll show you the code.

```
class LoginModel {

    var TAG = "LoginModel"
    private var ID: String
    private var PW: String
    var resultTxt: String = ""
    var auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    constructor(ID: String, PW: String) {
        this.ID = ID
        this.PW = PW
    }

    fun login(ID: String, PW: String) : String{
        this.ID = ID
        this.PW = PW
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(ID, PW)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            // 
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    resultTxt = "Login Success"
                } else {
                    resultTxt = "Login Failed"
                }
            }
       return resultTxt
       // I'd like to process the results based on the return.
       // But it doesn't return the way I want it.
       // I know it's related to asynchronous processing.
       // So where should I put the callback function, and how should I write 
       // it?
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps

Comment: please consider giving this question and answer an upvote, it's a basic example of how to do callbacks for people in future :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a callback to your login function which get invoked after `resultTxt` has been set. Something along the following lines should work,

```
class LoginModel {

    var TAG = "LoginModel"
    private var ID: String
    private var PW: String
    var resultTxt: String = ""
    var auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    constructor(ID: String, PW: String) {
        this.ID = ID
        this.PW = PW
    }

    fun login(ID: String, PW: String, callback: (String)->Unit) {
        this.ID = ID
        this.PW = PW
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(ID, PW)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            // 
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    resultTxt = "Login Success"
                } else {
                    resultTxt = "Login Failed"
                }
                //The callback get's invoked with your expected result value.
                callback.invoke(resultTxt)
            }
       //Don't return here
       //return resultTxt
       // I'd like to process the results based on the return.
       // But it doesn't return the way I want it.
       // I know it's related to asynchronous processing.
       // So where should I put the callback function, and how should I write 
       // it?
    }
}
```

You can then call the method using,

```
login(id,password) { result ->
    //Do what you want with the result here
}
```

Comment: I made this post specifically for callback related questions, please consider giving it an upvote if you think it could be useful :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android

Answer (score 2):

```
fun login(ID: String, PW: String, callback:(String) -> Unit) {
        this.ID = ID
        this.PW = PW
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(ID, PW)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    resultTxt = "Login Success"
                } else {
                    resultTxt = "Login Failed"
                }
                callback.invoke(resultTxt)
            }  
    }
```

try this as a callback, it will return the value of `resultTxt` after it has executed.

Then, when you call the login method:

```
login(ID,PW){ result ->
//here, result is the value of the callback 
}
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**

You can return the result and user of the call in a callback, like this:

```
 fun login(ID: String, PW: String, callback:(Boolean, User?) -> Unit) {
        this.ID = ID
        this.PW = PW
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(ID, PW)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                   callback.invoke(true, auth.currentUser)
                } else {
                  callback.invoke(false, null)
                }
            }  
    }
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
Login(id, password){ result: Boolean, user: User? ->
    if(result){
     //the result is successful 
     user?.let{ authUser ->
       //here, authUser is your user
     }
    } else{
    //the result was not successful
 }
}
```